# How can I create iterators of a filtered vector?

Tags: c++, lambda, filter, iterator, containers

Suppose I have a vector named `spot_deals` of `SpotDeal` that is a class:

```
class SpotDeal
{
public:
    int deal_id_; // primary key, and vector is sorted by id
    string ccy_pair_; // ccy pair, e.g. GBPUSD, AUDUSD
    double amount_;
}
```

Say I need to pass two subset of `spot_deals` to a function `foo` for some computation. I could make copies, however, that would cost memory and time. Actually `foo` only needs iterators of deals. So can I make 2 iterators of `vector<SpotDeal>`, namely `it1` and `it2` and pass them to `foo`?

The two subset of `spot_deals` could be filtered by `ccy_pair_`, e.g. deals of GBPUSD and AUDUSD, or by other conditions. So I'm looking for a way to define an iterator defined by a vector and a lambda function (could equivalently be a functor though).

Is there a way to write a helper function `make_filtered_iterator` so that I can have something like below?

```
auto it1 = make_filtered_iterator(spot_deals, filter_lambda1);
auto it2 = make_filtered_iterator(spot_deals, filter_lambda2);
foo(it1, it2);
```

Comment: @wallyk ?? i'm looking to  a way to implement `make_filtered_iterator` helper function... there's nothing to try yet...

Comment: did you see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html

Comment: @perreal thx pointing out that.. but boost is a bit too heavey, i'm trying to work with STL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is certainly "yes."  C++ iterators in the STL style can be made to do all sorts of tricks.  A common but basic one is making an iterator for `std::map` which when dereferenced gives only the key or the value.

In your particular case, a simple implementation might be like this:

```
template <typename BaseIterator>
struct filtered_iterator : BaseIterator
{
    typedef std::function<bool (const value_type&)> filter_type;

    filtered_iterator() = default;
    filtered_iterator(filter_type filter, BaseIterator base, BaseIterator end = {})
        : BaseIterator(base), _end(end), _filter(filter_type) {
        while (*this != _end && !_filter(**this)) {
            ++*this;
        }
    }

    filtered_iterator& operator++() {
        do {
            BaseIterator::operator++();
        } while (*this != _end && !_filter(**this));
    }

    filtered_iterator operator++(int) {
        filtered_iterator copy = *this;
        ++*this;
        return copy;
    }

private:
    BaseIterator _end;
    filter_type _filter;
};

template <typename BaseIterator>
filtered_iterator<BaseIterator> make_filtered_iterator(
        typename filtered_iterator<BaseIterator>::filter_type filter,
        BaseIterator base, BaseIterator end = {}) {
    return {filter, base, end};
}
```

I set a default value for `end` because typically you can use a default-constructed iterator for that.  But in some cases you might want to filter only a subset of the container, in which case specifying the end makes it easy.

Comment: i'm a bit lost at `BaseIterator end = {}`. as i understand normally `end` iterator sits after the last real element of the container, so the address in the memory varies for different container object, and it's only used for address comparision (i.e. the content in that address is invalid). how could such an iterator be default constructed by an empty braces?

Comment: @athos: Depends on the container.  In some cases iterator() is usable as "end" and in others it isn't.  Remove the default if you don't like it.

Comment: If you edited your code due to something I pointed out, you should mention that.

Comment: Ok. Seems I need understand more on iterations. Thx!

Comment: @PasserBy: I would instead like to credit Mark Meretzky at NYU for giving me the epiphany that C++ iterators can do basically anything.  Your note made me notice a bug in my original code, but that code was 100% untested anyway, so this is not significant to the demonstration.

Comment: The "bug" was half the actual logic, it was the difference between your implementation making sense and not. And regardless of scale, acknowledgement is just decency

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it would be possible to create an iterator type.   However, I suspect your question is an example of an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you want to find a way to operate differently on two subsets of a vector (X), have decided the solution must involve implementing a special-purpose iterator (Y), and have asked how to do Y rather than X.    I am going to provide an option to do X without needing to do Y.

I suggest it would be easier to use standard algorithm `std::stable_partition()` to separate the container into two ranges.

```
 auto false_partition = std::stable_partition(your_vector.begin(), your_vector.end(), your_filter);
```

The `begin()` and `end()` iterators of the vector do not change (i.e. are not invalidated), but the elements between them are reorganised into two ranges, such that the elements for which `your_filter` returns `true` precedes the set of elements for which `your_filter` returns `false`. `false_partition` is therefore simultaneously the "past the end" iterator for the first range, and the beginning of the second range.    The order of elements in each range is the same as in the original vector.

These can be used as follows

```
 //   a loop to operates on the elements for which your_filter returned true

 for (auto i = your_vector.begin(); i != false_partition; ++i)
 {
      // do whatever
 }

 //   a loop to operates on the elements for which your_filter returned false

 for (auto i = false_partition; i != your_vector.end(); ++i)
 {
      // do whatever
 }
```

Before C++11, the `auto` keyword can be replaced with appropriate iterator types (e.g. `std::vector<int>::iterator` or `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`, depending on whether you want the elements to be changed using the iterators).

Comment: thx for the reply but my problem is like this: suppose I have a string of `AakkafdBlkjfDadfkljXafd`, I'd like to generate a `map<char, string>` as `{['A', "akkafd"], ['B', "lkjf"], ['D', "adfklj"], ['X', "afd"]}`.

Comment: Thanks for confiming you have provided an XY problem, albeit a different X than I anticipated.  You really don't need to create a special iterator for that.   What you're describing is a trivial parsing exercise, and you've over-thought it.   Basic algorithm:  Find uppercase letter.  Start with an empty string.  Append characters from input to the string until another uppercase letter or end of input is found.  Do `your_map[uppercase_letter] = copied_string`.   Repeat until done.   You can do that with a single iterator that refers to elements of your input string.

Comment: how to find the "Next" upper case character? Of course this can be done by a loop, I'm trying to come out with an STL style solution

Comment: An "STL style solution" (whatever you think that means) does not have to mean creating funky iterators.    Have a look at the specification of various standard algorithms.   You might well be able to use a combination of standard algorithms to do what you want - and that would qualify as an "STL style solution".   The trick is doing what you want in a way that is as simple and clear as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I may suggest viewers of this question get a crash course with Eric Nibbler's rangev3 because that's the paradigm adopted for C++20 standard lib.

https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

How to do your filter iteration:

```
for (auto element : spot_deals | views::filter([](auto i) { return condition(i); }))
{ //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By chance, I've recently worked on this exact problem. As it turns out, filtering is the most complicated of quite some operations on a container, and also contains the most pitfalls.

```
template<typename Range, typename Pred>
class filter
{
public:
    friend class const_iterator;
    class const_iterator : public std::iterator_traits<typename Range::const_iterator>
    {
        using underlying = typename Range::const_iterator;
    public:
        auto operator*() {return *u;}
        const_iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++u;
            normalize();
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            auto t = *this;
            u++;
            normalize();
            return t;
        }
        bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const {return u == rhs.u;}
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const {return !(*this == rhs);}
    private:
        friend filter;
        const_iterator(underlying u, const filter& f) : u{std::move(u)}, f{f} {normalize();}
        void normalize()
        {
            for(; u != f.r.end() && !f.p(*u); u++);
        }

        underlying u;
        const filter& f;
    };

    filter(const Range& r, const Pred& p) : r{r}, p{p} {}

    auto begin() const {return const_iterator{r.begin(), *this};}
    auto end() const {return const_iterator{r.end(), *this};}

private:
    const Range& r;
    Pred p;
};
```

We use it as (with c++17 guide)

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto f = filter(v, [](int x){return x & 1;});
for(auto i : f)
    // all i in v that is odd
```

Let me explain the pitfalls:

- The first element might be filtered out, `*r.begin()` might not be an element in the filtered range. This means the iterator has to be checked on construction.
- `r.end()` might be invalidated without invalidating other iterators, that is to say, saving a copy of `r.end()` in any iterators to compare with is a logic error.
- `operator==` is not very straightforward, two underlying iterators referring to different elements in the original range might be referring to the same element in the filtered view because filtered out elements doesn't count as an element.

Comment: There's an compile error on `auto operator*() { return *u; }` saying "error C3551: expected a trailing return type", is it that I need modify the code somehow for VS2013?

Comment: @athos You need c++14 or above

Comment: I encountered segfaults when using this code and passing a lambda with captures as the 2nd argument to `filter()`. This can be fixed by changing the type of filter::p from `const Pred&` to just `Pred` (non reference).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use iterators pointing to your original vector, because they cannot convey the size of your subsets. (Basically, you would need one more iterator per subset to represent the end of the subsets.) As of [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), I would work with *ranges* from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), as mentioned in [v.oddou's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57867653/2675154) answer. More specifically, for your use case, I would use the range adaptor `std::views::filter` as follows:

```
auto gbpusd = [](const auto& sd) { return sd.ccy_pair_ == "GBPUSD"; };
auto audusd = [](const auto& sd) { return sd.ccy_pair_ == "AUDUSD"; };

auto range1 = spot_deals | std::views::filter(gbpusd);
auto range2 = spot_deals | std::views::filter(audusd);

foo(range1, range2);
```

This solution does not create temporary vectors for the filtered spot deals, because the view adaptors create ranges that don't contain elements. The resulting ranges `range1` and `range2` are just views over the vector `spot_deals`, but with customized iteration behaviors.

The declaration of `foo()` is a bit tricky, because the data types of the ranges are quite complex. I would therefore use the placeholder type `auto` for the function parameters and thus make `foo()` a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

```
void foo(auto& r1, auto& r2) {
    for (auto const& sd : r1)
        std::cout << sd.deal_id_ << std::endl;
    for (auto const& sd : r2)
        std::cout << sd.amount_ << std::endl;
}
```

(Alternatively, you could pass `spot_deals` by reference to `foo()` and declare the filtered ranges inside `foo()`.)

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pnjJvut5PBIp6RwS)