# Is there a way to loop over the elements in multiset or unordered_set while deleting and insert elements in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-set, multiset

I want to loop over each element in the multiset or unordered_set and during the loop, I could insert and remove the element.
For example:

```
unordere_set<int> myset = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (auto it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it) {
    myset.erase(*it);
    // do something that needs to use the set without *it like in a recursion function that takes the reference of the set
    myset.insert(*it);      
}
```

I don't want to create a copy of the set since the set could be very large and it is not very efficient.

Comment: When you say _use the set without *it_ do you mean the following code won't use `it` or you wish to operate on the `set` without that particular member (e.g. on first iteration do something with the set without the element `1`)? You might wanna just make your function take a reference to the set, and a reference to the iterator you _don't_ wish to operate on

Comment: I mean I wish to operate on the set without that particular member.

Comment: Maybe use a [filter iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350760/501250)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with this code (untested though)

```
unordered_set<int> myset = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (auto it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ) {
    auto save = *it;
    it = myset.erase(it);
    // do something that needs to use the set without *it like in a recursion function that takes the reference of the set
    myset.insert(save);      
}
```

My reasoning is that `mysave.insert(save)` should not invalidate the iterator `it` because it will not cause rehashing of the unordered_set, since all you are doing is adding back an element that was previously deleted. But of course it does depend on exactly what you are doing with `// do something ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid inserting and deleting while traversing. Here is a bad suggestion.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  unordered_set<int> s { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  vector<unordered_set<int>::const_iterator> s_add;
  vector<unordered_set<int>::const_iterator> s_del;
  for (auto itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); ++itr) {
    // Some conditions
    s_add.push_back(itr);
    // Some conditions
    s_del.push_back(itr);
  }

  for (auto itr : s_add) {
    s.insert(*itr);
  }

  for (auto itr : s_del) {
    s.erase(itr);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cpprefrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert), insertion may affect all the iterators over `unordered_set` container.

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are
> invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not
> invalidated. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is
> greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.
>
> If the insertion is
> successful, pointers and references to the element obtained while it
> is held in the node handle are invalidated, and pointers and
> references obtained to that element before it was extracted become
> valid.

I was wondering if you just want to iterate over a container and do some insert/delete operations on it, why don't you just use `std::vector` container and element indexes to insert/delete them.

If you insist on using `unordered_set`, you can use `std::next` in a `while` loop to iterate over your `unordered_set` container and do some insert/delete operation on it.

Note that because you will insert the same element at the end of the loop, it will not trigger the rehashing algorithm.

```cpp
unordered_set<int> myset = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
unordered_set<int>::iterator it = myset.begin();
int i = 0;

while (it != myset.end()) {

    myset.erase(*it);
    // do something that needs to use the set without *it like in a recursion function that takes the reference of the set
    myset.insert(*it);
    it = next(myset.begin(), ++i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```
multiset<int> myset = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
while(myset.begin()!=myset.end()) {
    myset.erase(myset.begin());
    //     or
    myset.erase(3);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).